# java find value of an xml attribute

Tags: java, xml

this is my xml :

<-tobject.subject tobject.subject.refnum="01016000" />

<-tobject.subject tobject.subject.refnum="10004000" />

I want to extract 01016000 and 10004000 from it .

I used this code:

NodeList nodeLst4 = doc.getElementsByTagName("tobject.subject");

```
        if (nodeLst4 != null) {

            int numberofCOdes = nodeLst4.getLength();

            aSubjectCodes = new String[numberofCOdes];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofCOdes; i++) {

             XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

             aSubjectCodes[i] = xpath.evaluate("//tobject.subject/@tobject.subject.refnum", doc);
```

the problem is that when i loop through it the evaluate method just return first number and do not give me the second value.

and i am not sure if using  xpath.evaluate is good idea or not.

Thanks

Comment: reformatted code, please revert if incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no need to use the doc.getElementsByTagName.
You are mixing plain DOM with XPath.

Your xpath is correct:

```
package net.davymeers;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XpathTest {
    private static String XMLSTRING = "<data>"
            + "<tobject.subject tobject.subject.refnum=\"01016000\" />\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "<tobject.subject tobject.subject.refnum=\"10004000\" />"
            + "</data>";

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Document doc = createDocument();
        final XPath xpath = createXpath();

        final NodeList nodes = findElements(
                "//tobject.subject/@tobject.subject.refnum", doc, xpath);
        final Collection<String> results = convertToCollection(nodes);

        for (final String result : results) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }

    private static Document createDocument() {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            final DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget
                                                            // this!
            final DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(XMLSTRING
                    .getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {
            // TODO handle exception
        } catch (final SAXException exception) {
            // TODO handle exception
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            // TODO handle exception
        } catch (final ParserConfigurationException exception) {
            // TODO handle exception
        }
        return doc;
    }

    private static XPath createXpath() {
        final XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        final XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        return xpath;
    }

    private static NodeList findElements(final String xpathExpression,
            final Document doc, final XPath xpath) {
        NodeList nodes = null;
        if (doc != null) {
            try {
                final XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);
                final Object result = expr
                        .evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                nodes = (NodeList) result;
            } catch (final XPathExpressionException exception) {
                // TODO handle exception
            }
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    private static Collection<String> convertToCollection(final NodeList nodes) {
        final Collection<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (nodes != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                result.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: tanx 
i used it but it gives 01016000 two times and it did not extract 10004000 
i dont know the reason

Regards

Comment: I did again a double check: i get the two values, as expected. Did you adapt something in the codesample?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful class I found a while back for XMLFiles. Takes a lot of the work off of your shoulders.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

/**
 * XMLFile.java
 * 
 * XML file object that represents an xml file and its properties. Used to
 * simplify the process of reading from and writing to XML files.
 * 
 * Derived from unknown source. Implemented on 12/03/09. Permission given to
 * implement and modify code.
 */

public class XMLFile {

    private String name;
    private String content;
    private Map<String, String> nameAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, List<XMLFile>> nameChildren = new HashMap<String, List<XMLFile>>();

    private static Element rootElement(String filename, String rootName) {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(fileInputStream);
            Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
            if (!rootElement.getNodeName().equals(rootName))
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not find root node: "
                        + rootName);
            return rootElement;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param (String) Filepath of XML File (String) Root of XML File
     **/
    public XMLFile(String filename, String rootName) {
        this(rootElement(filename, rootName));
    }

    /**
     * @param (Element) XML File Element
     **/
    private XMLFile(Element element) {
        this.name = element.getNodeName();
        this.content = element.getTextContent();
        NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap = element.getAttributes();
        int n = namedNodeMap.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Node node = namedNodeMap.item(i);
            String name = node.getNodeName();
            addAttribute(name, node.getNodeValue());
        }
        NodeList nodes = element.getChildNodes();
        n = nodes.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(i);
            int type = node.getNodeType();
            if (type == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                addChild(node.getNodeName(), new XMLFile((Element) node));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds attribute to ???
     * 
     * @param (String) Attribute Name (String) Attribute Value
     **/
    private void addAttribute(String name, String value) {
        nameAttributes.put(name, value);
    }

    /**
     * Adds child directory to ???
     * 
     * @param (String) Name of New Child Directory (XMLFile) XML Documentation
     *        of Child
     **/
    private void addChild(String name, XMLFile child) {
        List<XMLFile> children = nameChildren.get(name);
        if (children == null) {
            children = new ArrayList<XMLFile>();
            nameChildren.put(name, children);
        }
        children.add(child);
    }

    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    public String content() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     *
     **/
    public XMLFile child(String name) {
        List<XMLFile> children = children(name);
        if (children.size() != 1)
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not find individual child node: "
                    + name);
        return children.get(0);
    }

    /**
     *
     **/
    public List<XMLFile> children(String name) {
        List<XMLFile> children = nameChildren.get(name);
        return children == null ? new ArrayList<XMLFile>() : children;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of a specific field and converts it to a String object
     * 
     * @param (String) Name of Field
     **/
    public String string(String name) {
        String value = nameAttributes.get(name);
        if (value == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not find attribute: " + name
                    + ", in node: " + this.name);
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of a specific field and converts it to an int
     * 
     * @param (String) Name of Field
     **/
    public int integer(String name) {
        return Integer.parseInt(string(name));
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of a specific field and converts it to an
     * ArrayList<String>
     * 
     * @param (String) Name of Field
     **/
    public ArrayList<String> arrayListString(String name) {
        String left = new String();
        int finished = 0;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            left = nameAttributes.get(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        while (finished == 0) {
            if (left.indexOf(", ") > -1) {
                list.add(left.substring(0, left.indexOf(", ")));
                left = left.substring(left.indexOf(", ") + 2);
            } else {
                list.add(left);
                finished = 1;
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Since his problem related to the way he was using xpath, i do not really see the relation with your post.

Comment: I was trying to give an alternative solution to help future issues, but I'll accept the down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you? I am parsing RSS XML from here:

http://www.kraftfoods.com/rss/dinnerRecipes.aspx

Look at Media and URL towards the bottom:

```
    package recipeSearchAndFinder.xml;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class DomFeedParser extends BaseFeedParser {

    public DomFeedParser(String feedUrl) {
        super(feedUrl);
    }

    public List<Message> parse() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(this.getInputStream());
            Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName(ITEM);
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Message message = new Message();
                Node item = items.item(i);
                NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node property = properties.item(j);
                    String name = property.getNodeName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
                        message.setTitle(property.getFirstChild()
                                .getNodeValue());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
                        message.setLink(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)) {
                        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                        NodeList chars = property.getChildNodes();
                        for (int k = 0; k < chars.getLength(); k++) {
                            text.append(chars.item(k).getNodeValue());
                        }
                        message.setDescription(text.toString());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PUB_DATE)) {
                        message.setDate(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(MEDIA)) {
                        NamedNodeMap nMap = property.getAttributes();
                        String mediaurl = nMap.getNamedItem("url")
                                .getNodeValue();
                        message.setMedia(mediaurl);
                    }
                }
                messages.add(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return messages;
    }
}
```